# How to add image watermark on image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to open images in a lightbox but I want a watermark image in right-bottom corner when the images are opened. So this is my code that I am using.

HTML

```
<div><a class="fancybox" href="pic1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title=""><img src="pic1.jpg" alt="1" /></a></div>
```

CSS

```
        .list_carousel {
            width: 100%;

        }
        .list_carousel ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 5.8%;
            margin-bottom: -90%;
        }
        .list_carousel li {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }
        .list_carousel.responsive {
            width: auto;
            margin-left: 0;
        }
```

JS

```
$(function() {
$('#foo4').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        scroll: 1,
        items: {
            height: '30%',
                visible: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 1
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: Why do you want to watermark with js/html? People can just remove it. I suggest swapping out images with an actual watermarked image.

Comment: Image watermark? Text watermark? What have you tried? The code you posted has nothing to do with a watermark.

Comment: a permanent watermark? or something to preview online?

Comment: Because the image is exported from a paint app. So if I have watermark image on canvas background people can easily to draw over it

Comment: please elaborate? if you want it for security reasons then as Mark said you should make the watermarked images permenant and keeping the originals somewhere else.. but if you still want it you can get some ready JS that manipulates images and can add alpha trait (transperencey) to the watermarking and preview it on top of the image using CSS, or load the image and watermark in a canvas so the originals are hidden..

Comment: So how I said I want an image watermark when the images is opened on lightbox. I can't create a permanent watermark because is exported from a paint app

Answer (score 0):

To make water mark on image best method is while uploading and adding water mark

and her is the method **rename your water mark file as `watermark.png`**

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES['image_file']))
{
    $max_size = 800; //max image size in Pixels
    $destination_folder = 'images/';
    $watermark_png_file = 'watermark.png'; //watermark png file

    $image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
    $image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size']; //file size
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp
    $image_type = $_FILES['image_file']['type']; //file type

    switch(strtolower($image_type)){ //determine uploaded image type 
            //Create new image from file
            case 'image/png': 
                $image_resource =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $image_resource =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp);
                break;          
            case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
                $image_resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp);
                break;
            default:
                $image_resource = false;
        }

    if($image_resource){
        //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
        list($img_width, $img_height) = getimagesize($image_temp);

        //Construct a proportional size of new image
        $image_scale        = min($max_size / $img_width, $max_size / $img_height); 
        $new_image_width    = ceil($image_scale * $img_width);
        $new_image_height   = ceil($image_scale * $img_height);
        $new_canvas         = imagecreatetruecolor($new_image_width , $new_image_height);

        if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $image_resource , 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_image_width, $new_image_height, $img_width, $img_height))
        {

            if(!is_dir($destination_folder)){ 
                mkdir($destination_folder);//create dir if it doesn't exist
            }

            //center watermark
            $watermark_left = ($new_image_width/2)-(300/2); //watermark left
            $watermark_bottom = ($new_image_height/2)-(100/2); //watermark bottom

            $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($watermark_png_file); //watermark image
            imagecopy($new_canvas, $watermark, $watermark_left, $watermark_bottom, 0, 0, 300, 100); //merge image

            //output image direcly on the browser.
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg($new_canvas, NULL , 90);
            imagejpeg($new_canvas, $destination_folder.'/'.$image_name , 90);
            //free up memory
            imagedestroy($new_canvas); 
            imagedestroy($image_resource);
            die();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

best method for creating water mark